# Просмотреть запись ВК

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как можно засчитать свой просмотр на запись ВК, чтобы изменилось поле записи `views`?

Есть аналогичный метод в сообщениях: `messages.markAsRead` и в историях: `stories.markSeen`.

При `wall.get` изменений в записи не происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод stats.viewPosts, строкой список id постов через запятую (owner_id+"_"+post_id) в параметре post_ids. Если просмотрен репост, нужно передать id оригинальных постов в repost_ids. 
Встречный вопрос: stories.markSeen пробовал, но почему-то не работает, пишет ошибку Unknown method passed, что не так с ним?:/

Comment: Не знаю, использовал год назад вот так:
user.stories.markSeen(owner_id = 12345, story_id = 12345, v = 5.102). Спасибо за ответ!